# Issues Calling Sybase Stored Procedure from C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, sybase

I'm trying to call a stored procedure in Sybase that inserts values I pass. I have been using this to get data:

```
 PlayerDbContext db = new PlayerDbContext();       
 String commandString = String.Format(
            "CALL DBA.SP_Player_crud(@id= '{0}',@option = '{1}')",
            playerId,
            "S");

 return db.Database.SqlQuery<Player>(commandString).FirstOrDefault();
```

This returns a player object, which works fine. The option is a flag that is used in the stored procedure to select data (S = Select) or insert data (I = Insert).

This is the insert which does not work even though it is the same stored procedure that is being called:

```
 PlayerDbContext db = new PlayerDbContext();       
 String commandString = String.Format(
            "CALL DBA.SP_Player_crud(@id= '{0}',@name = '{1}', @option = '{2}')",
            playerId,
            name,
            "I");

 return db.Database.SqlQuery<Player>(commandString);
```

The difference is that in the stored procedure this one inserts the name field. I realize this does not return a player object (which I suspect is part of the problem), but why does this not still work? Is there a way to just call this stored procedure without expecting anything back? I tried ExecuteSqlCommand without any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps your stored procedure has a bug, but without that code...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried calling the stored procedure directly in the Sybase interactive console and it inserted correctly with the same string that was passed through from the code.

Comment: It could be the `ConnectionString`, sometimes you have to anchor to the parent instance rather than a specific node to do certain functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Greg. Could you elaborate a bit more? Considering what I discovered below, I don't believe this would be the issue, but do you find it still a possibility?

Comment: @BradGermain Yeah, it potentially could be.  I had a similar problem when I was attempting to restore a backup from one database to a newly created database all through code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but I was able to resolve the issue by modifying the stored procedure to return the select statement as well. So, the data gets inserted, then the stored procedure does a select which returns the results. With this change, the stored procedure is executed correctly.

My guess is the problem has to do with what is being returned and that it is not matching my entity. I'm not sure what gets sent by default when there is no select, but perhaps knowing that would also be helpful in solving this.

If anyone else has any input, please respond as I'd like to know the proper way to handle this.